# Name for newly joined employees

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there any word to indicate newly joined members in the company? I use

1. New joinees
2. New recruits
3. Freshers
4. Newly appointed.

But I want the correct word.

Comment: Location may make a difference.  Such persons are often called "new hires" in the US, but this may not be common in other places.  In the US, :"new recruits" sounds military, while "newly appointed" may apply to more official positions.  The first and third terms do not occur commonly in the US.

Comment: Do you want a formal term or informal one?

Comment: @Rob_Ster: Consider posting that as an answer. *Newhire* or *new hire* is definitely the term most used in the US, in my experience.

Comment: What does your own language to English dictionary or online dictionary say? In what context will you use this word? To compare incoming new employees with outgoing employees? Can you write an example sentence? The following is the rule of this community. **Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered**.

Comment: They might be your *intake*, your *scrubs*, your *rookies*, and many other terms. Certain terminology is specific to certain professions, industries, or individual organizations, and may vary depending on whether the new employee is a lateral hire or an entry-level recruit. You really need to explain the context and how you plan to use the word before we can offer meaningful answers.

Answer (score 1):

Among different options, as ***[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=new%20employee%2Cnew%20hire%2C%20new%20recruit&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnew%20employee%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnew%20hire%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnew%20recruit%3B%2Cc0)*** shows, the more common  expression is "***new employee***" both in AmE and BrE.

[Recruit](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/recruit) is mainly a military term:

> - a new ​member of an ​organization, ​especially the ​army.

[Fresher](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fresher) is used mainly in school/university contexts:

> - a ​student who has ​recently ​started ​studying at a ​college or ​university.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Comment: It seems to me that "recruit" can be used in a non-military sense as a new member of a group or organization. It is used as such (recrue) in French, at least. I would not used "new recruit", which seems a little redundant

Comment: @LaurentDuval -  usage  is mainly in the military context, but as said above it may refer also to other organizations.  Recruit: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/recruit

Comment: 'Fresher' is also used for employees in Indian English.

Answer (score 0):

In the world of human resources (at least in the United States) the terms "joiner processing" and "leaver processing" are in common use.  Some places even have a "mover process" for promotions and transfers.  I could not find references to a definition, *per se*, but [this article](https://info.kalkiconsulting.com/blog/preventing-insider-misuse-through-joiners-movers-leavers-processes/) is a good example of the terms' usage.

The joiner process encompasses things like filling out tax and immigration forms, electing insurance options, setting up AD and email accounts, and all those things you do in the first few days at a new job.  The leaver process, of course, disables all your accounts, turns off your pay check, and so on.

In conclusion, simply call them "joiners."

Comment: I don't work in HR, but I've never heard those terms used in the US. In my experience, the term used most in the US, including by HR (e.g., in official documents) is *new hire* (or *newhire* or *new-hire*).

Answer (score 0):

'Probationer', until we decide whether they're worth their salt (usually a pre-determined period, which may be extended in the event of performance inadequacies).

Answer (score 0):

New Hirees

Not sure if that's an actual word but its what we use and it drives the point home directly to the spirit of identity, for someone just brought on board in a company seeting as an employee.

Answer (score -1):

An informal term that is currently in vogue is *noob* (as an abbreviation for *newbie*).

Comment: *Newbie* means new to anything, not necessarily a new hire (newly hired employee).

Answer (score -1):

[Newcomers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newcomer) is a generic option.

Answer (score -1):

I would strongly recommend : Neophytes OR Just- joined OR Rookies.